# Have to click twice to update state (useState hook) with onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I've seen more questions being post here about this, but the solutions did not work for me.

The problem is that I: **have to click twice to update the state of a constant defined using the useState hook**
How can I make this work only having to click once?

Please see the code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hoover-hxg7g?file=/src/App.js), or the code below:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Row from "./Row";

export default function App() {
  const [adults, setAdults] = useState(1);
  return <Row adults={adults} setAdults={setAdults} />;
}
```

**Row.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function({ adults, setAdults }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(adults);
  }, [adults]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setAdults(adults++)}>{adults}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try `setAdults(v => v + 1)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do:

```
setAdults(adults+1)
```

or:

```
setAdults(++adults)
```

Be careful using `++` because `someObject.counter++` will mutate `someObject`.